# How to display a Windows 7 style context menu?

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-7, contextmenu, aero

[image: Context menus]

In my .NET applications, context menus look like the left one.

How can I apply the Windows 7 style on them in order to make them look like the right one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click the tool box, Choose Items.  Tick "ContextMenu", the one with Namespace = System.Windows.Forms and Directory = Global Assembly Cache.

This .NET 1.x component is distinct from ContextMenuStrip, it uses native Windows menus.  You'll lose some capabilities, I doubt you care.  You'll need to write a line of code to assign the menu, the designer only lets you set the ContextMenuStrip property.  Add that line to the constructor, like:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ContextMenu = contextMenu1;
    }
```

Comment: Is there some alternative solution? I need to assign the menu to the `ContextMenuStrip` property of a `NotifyIcon`, and `ContextMenu`s aren't supported.

Comment: @minitech simply set `notifyIcon.ContextMenu = contextMenu1` as well

Comment: @lawrance.shepstone: Oh, thanks. I must have missed the part about the designer last time :D

Comment: Will it work with dynamically added standard `ToolStripMenuItem` controls?